# How to show google map and marker on the same layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, marker

**Goal**

When show map button is clicked, I would like to start a new activity (which i called MapActivity) where google maps and a marker needs to be displayed.

[Main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgrwd.png)

**Where am I**

When "Show Map" button is clicked, a new activity gets started with Maps and Marker but both layouts are overlaid.

[Map and Marker Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Phh.png)

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.find);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Spinner fromSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.from);
                Spinner toSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.to);

                Location fromLocation = (Location) fromSpinner.getSelectedItem();
                Location toLocation = (Location) toSpinner.getSelectedItem();

                new ShortestDistanceTask(fromLocation, toLocation).execute();
            }
        });

    }

    public void onShowMap(View v){
        if (v.getId() == R.id.showMap){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

**MapActivity.class**

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

        FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
        Marker_Activity MA = new Marker_Activity();
        FT.add(R.id.maplayout   ,MA);
        FT.commit();
    }
}
```

**Marker_Activity.class**

```
public class Marker_Activity extends Fragment {
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    private static final LatLng Echostar = new LatLng(10,20);

    public void processMap(View v){
        if(googleMap == null){
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }

        if(googleMap != null){
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Echostar).title("This is the marked area"));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Echostar,100));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_activity, container, false);
        processMap(v);
        return v;
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="innoday.echostar.com.echopath.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/from"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/to"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Find"
            android:id="@+id/find"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Map"
            android:id="@+id/showMap"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="onShowMap" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.23"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/table">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**map_activity.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/maplayout" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please click on "Main page" and "Map and Marker Activity" hyperlinks for images

Comment: why you take Relative layout in map Activity?

Comment: Im a newbie to android programming. I was following a documentation where they were using relative layout.

Comment: try from this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a google_maps.xml file

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/mapviewfragment"/>
```

where mapviewfragment.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/googlemap" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

This way your google map can take the whole screen and marker can be shown on it.

Your MapActivity should implement

`GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`,

`GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`,

`OnMapReadyCallback`,

`LocationListener`

and override atleast

`onMapReady()`,

`onLocationChanged()`,

`onConnected()` methods.

Comment: How are google_maps.xml and mapviewfragment.xml are used?